# jQuery url - editurl -> is there also a addurl

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, jqgrid

Hi I have a problem in a `jquery` `asp.net` project:
I have on one page 2 grids - the main grid is loaded while the second grid is disabled(hidden). When I click on one row in the main grid the second grid is shown then and shows the data if some exist regarding to this row. If there is now data I want to create new data in the second grid. I tried to handle this with url (to get the data), editurl (to modify existing data) which works fine and now I need e.g. a addurl to create new data.
Has anyone an idea to fix this problem because I didn't really found something on the net about this..

```
onSelectRow: function (id) {
    var rid = jQuery('#tblJQGridBereitschaft').jqGrid("getGridParam", "selrow");
    if (rid) {
        var row = jQuery('#tblJQGridBereitschaft').jqGrid("getRowData", rid);
    }
    var bs_id = row.ID;
    function seturl(bs_id){
        jQuery("#tblJQGridBereitschaftFahrtkosten").setGridParam({ loadonce: false })
        jQuery("#tblJQGridBereitschaftFahrtkosten").setGridParam({ datatype: "json" })
        jQuery("#tblJQGridBereitschaftFahrtkosten").setGridParam({ url: '@Url.Action("GetFahrtkosten", "Bereitschaft")?BS_ID=' + bs_id +'', page: 1 }).trigger('reloadGrid');
        jQuery("#tblJQGridBereitschaftFahrtkosten").setGridParam({ editurl: '@Url.Action("ModifyFahrtkosten", "Bereitschaft")?BS_ID=' + bs_id, page: 1 }).trigger('reloadGrid');
        // Here I need the "addurl"
        jQuery("#tblJQGridBereitschaftFahrtkosten").setGridParam({ loadonce: true })
    }
    seturl(bs_id);
    $("#headerFahrtkosten").show();
    $("#jqgrid_containerfahrtkosten").show();
},
```

Thanks for any help or tips!

Comment: Did you take a look at custom buttons? http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:custom_buttons

Comment: No but how should this help me, I don't need a custom button I think, I have the jqgrid and when I click on the '+' button of the grid the pop-up window is shown and then I write in my data and click on submit button to save the data in the database. When I just edit a row with this code this works fine and now I need something like "editurl" just for create like "addurl"